# Open Google Play / Rate App in Phonegap App

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I want to open a confirmation window that pops up when the app starts. If you click ok, you should be redirected to the google play store to rate the app. The InAppView is a very bad solution to rate the app it really should open in the native app store app.

I tried this but it doesn´t work:

```
window.open("market://details?id=com.publishername.myapp");
```

and also this:

```
window.open("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.YourApp", "_system");
```

I´ve read through some other threads but the "solutions" did not work..

Is there a way to redirect the user to the Play Store to rate the app?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you can use simple plugin for open the web browser with link.

Comment: create plugin for open the web browser with link.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the Rating code should be handled from android side.
Below is the code for that :

```
public static void showRateDialog(final Context mContext) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    builder.setMessage(
            "If you enjoy using "
                    + APP_TITLE
                    + ", please take a moment to rate it. Thanks for your support!")
            .setTitle("Rate " + APP_TITLE)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setPositiveButton("Rate TempleRun2",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            mContext.startActivity(new Intent(
                                    Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                    Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.imangi.templerun2")));


                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("Remind me later",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            dialog.cancel();
                        }

                    })
            .setNeutralButton("No\nThanks",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }

                    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. Since i am not very familiar with java and i am using phonegap, how can i connect this with a javascript function? Or where do i have to paste this so that it will work?

Comment: I always used a simple "rate me" function that I wrote a while ago, but you did a nice looking simple one man :), thanks ,I'll be using yours.